# How to keep substring until character is found in Polars DataFrame?

Tags: python, string, python-polars

I am working with a Polars DataFrame that contains a column with values like this:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────────┬──────────────┐
│      A       │      B       │
│     ---      │     ---      │
│     str      │     str      │
├──────────────┼──────────────┤
│  A|B:0d:cs   │    C:2ew2    │
├──────────────┼──────────────┤
│    A:1ds0    │   E|F:91we23 │
├──────────────┼──────────────┤
│ QW|P:3dwsd   │   A|Z:12w219 │
└──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

I want to extract the left substring from each cell in the DataFrame until I find the character ":". The desired result should look like this:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────────┬──────────────┐
│      A       │      B       │
│     ---      │     ---      │
│     str      │     str      │
├──────────────┼──────────────┤
│     A|B      │      C       │
├──────────────┼──────────────┤
│      A       │     E|F      │
├──────────────┼──────────────┤
│    QW|P      │     A|Z      │
└──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.split.html) and [`list.first()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.first.html):

```py
df.select(pl.all().str.split(':').list.first())

┌─────────┬───────┐
│ integer ┆ float │
│ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ str     ┆ str   │
╞═════════╪═══════╡
│ A|B     ┆ C     │
│ A       ┆ E|F   │
│ QW|P    ┆ A|Z   │
└─────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: I'd argue the usage of `pl.all()` and `Expr.list.first()` here is cleaner than the accepted solution using generator expressions and `Expr.list.get(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also replace the character and "everything" after it with "nothing".

- [`.str.replace()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.replace.html#polars.Expr.str.replace)

```py
df.with_columns(pl.all().str.replace(r":.*", ""))
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ B   │
│ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╡
│ A|B  ┆ C   │
│ A    ┆ E|F │
│ QW|P ┆ A|Z │
└──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: that is an interesting approach for sure

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split using `:` and select the first item from the resulting list.

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> 
>>> df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "integer": ["A|B:0d:cs", "A:1ds0", "QW|P:3dwsd"],
...         "float": ["C:2ew2 ", "E|F:91we23", "A|Z:12w219"],
...     }
... )
>>> df
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ integer    ┆ float      │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ str        ┆ str        │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ A|B:0d:cs  ┆ C:2ew2     │
│ A:1ds0     ┆ E|F:91we23 │
│ QW|P:3dwsd ┆ A|Z:12w219 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
>>> df.with_columns(pl.col(col).str.split(":").list.get(0) for col in df.columns)
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬───────┐
│ integer ┆ float │
│ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ str     ┆ str   │
╞═════════╪═══════╡
│ A|B     ┆ C     │
│ A       ┆ E|F   │
│ QW|P    ┆ A|Z   │
└─────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide this answer! While it does work correctly, it tends to perform slowly when working with DataFrames containing thousands of cells.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be used in polars.
Use the method that selects the characters up to
the first match ":" in the string.
Sample code is most simple to each columns.

same result by regular expressions;

```py
df.select(pl.all().str.extract(r"(^.+?):"))
df.select(pl.col("*").str.extract(r"(^.+?):"))
df.select(pl.col("A","B").str.extract(r"(^.+?):"))
```

Same result, use `split()` makes list of strings ;

```py
df.select(pl.all().str.split(':').list[0])
```

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [" A|B:0d:cs", "A:1ds0", "QW|P:3dwsd"],
    "B": [" C:2ew2","E|F:91we23","A|Z:12w219"]
    }
)

df.select( 
    pl.col("A").str.extract(r"(^.+?):"),
    pl.col("B").str.extract(r"(^.+?):")
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ B   │
│ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╡
│ A|B  ┆ C   │
│ A    ┆ E|F │
│ QW|P ┆ A|Z │
└──────┴─────┘
```